# How to remove an entry in a list based on a value in the sublist

Tags: python, list

I have a list as below:

```
list = [ [1,2,3,4,5], 
         [1,2,3,3,5], 
         [1,2,3,2,5], 
         [1,2,3,4,6] ]
```

I would like to parse through this list and remove the entry if it satisfy below conditions:

1. if `list[i][0]` is the same as `list[i+1][0]` AND
2. if `list[i][4]` is the same as `list[i+1][4]`

which will result in below list:

```
list = [ [1,2,3,4,5],
         [1,2,3,4,6]]
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Using Python 2.5.4

Comment: Just a remark: from your description I would have removed entries 0 and 1 (because of indexation of your conditions).

Comment: @Howard You are right. It could be the deletion of entry 0 and 1 too. Depending on how the solution is implemented. In any case, both are ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to keep everything not matching the condition:

```
[sublist for i, sublist in enumerate(yourlist)
    if i + 1 == len(yourlist) or (sublist[0], sublist[4]) != (yourlist[i+1][0], yourlist[i + 1][4])]
```

So, any row that is either the last one, or one where the first and last element do not match the same columns in the next row is allowed.

Result:

```
>>> [sublist for i, sublist in enumerate(yourlist)
...     if i + 1 == len(yourlist) or (sublist[0], sublist[4]) != (yourlist[i+1][0], yourlist[i + 1][4])]
[[1, 2, 3, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Less concise non-list comprehension version.

```
list = [ [1,2,3,4,5], 
         [1,2,3,3,5], 
         [1,2,3,2,5], 
         [1,2,3,4,6] ]

output = []

for i, v in enumerate(list):
    if i +1 < len(list):
        if not (list[i][0] == list[i+1][0] and list[i][4] == list[i+1][4]):
            output.append(v)
    else:
        output.append(v)

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put some `itertools` on the table :-)

```
from itertools import izip_longest

l = [ [1,2,3,4,5], 
      [1,2,3,3,5], 
      [1,2,3,2,5], 
      [1,2,3,4,6] ]

def foo(items):
    for c, n in izip_longest(items, items[1:]):
        if not n or c[0] != n[0] or c[4] != n[4]:
            yield c

print list(foo(l))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

If you don't mind that this don't work in place put rather creates a new `list`.

**Edit:**

Since you told us you are using 2.5.4, you can use a method like the following instead of `izip_longest`:

```
# warning! items must not be empty :-)
def zip_longest(items):
    g = iter(items)
    next(g)
    for item in items:
        yield item, next(g, None)
```

Comment: I don't mind creating a new list. But i'm currently using 2.6, so no izip_longest.

Comment: [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) is avaiable in 2.6

Comment: sorry my bad, i'm using 2.5.4 :|

ImportError: cannot import name izip_longest

Comment: Well, I edited my answer to include a replacement for `izip_longest`, but note that you could also use a list comprehension as shown in Martijn's answer if you don't want to add two new functions to your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think list comprehension is best for this code.

```
res = [value for index, value in enumerate(a) if not (index < len(a)-1 and value[0]==a[index+1][0] and value[4]==a[index+1][4])]
```